# How to find all global variables in C++ source code, DLL or any file created by the VC++ compiler?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++, thread-safety

I'm making my application thread-safe. One of the steps is to synchronize access or eliminate usages of global variables. I'm using Visual Studio. I can't find any good way to find all global variables in my codebase. It's impossible to create a good text search pattern and I can't find any helpful tool. Do you guys know any good way to do that? It could be a source code analysis tool or a binary file analyzer.

Comment: What's wrong with "static but not const" expressed in your favourite script language as a search pattern?

Comment: That finds class- and function-level statics, too. Good thing in this case, as they also need synchronization, but it doesn't precisely answer the question from the title.

Comment: If you have globals they are used across translation units, thus you will have `extern` declarations in header files; finding them should be easy since the `extern` keyword not followed by a quoted string in practice is used only for this.

Comment: Matteo Italia, not exact. Global variable is extern by default (in C/C++); and two declaration with same name, type and initializer (if any) will be merged by linker.

Answer (score 15):

This could help:

1. Open the project in visual studio.
2. Open 'Class View' of the project
3. Under the project title, you will find 'Global Functions and Variable'.

I have checked this with Visual Studio 2010 and above.

***Edit:*** As suggested by [Ajay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264325/ajay) in comments, you could also categorize items in groups. For grouping items:

1. In class view, right click on project title
2. Select `Group By Object/Member Type'
3. Select the required tree like variables or structures or enums etc.

Comment: It does help! Additional tip: After launching 'Class View', nightstick and select "Group By Member Type", and then select "Variables" tree.

Answer (score 8):

One option might be letting the linker generate a map file (/MAP in Visual Studio).

You will get a .map file for each binary with two sections:

**A table of segments**

```
 Start         Length     Name                   Class
 0001:00000000 00010000H .textbss                DATA
 0002:00000000 000034b4H .text                   CODE
 0003:00000000 00000104H .CRT$XCA                DATA
 0003:00000104 00000104H .CRT$XCAA               DATA
 0003:00000208 00000104H .CRT$XCZ                DATA
 0003:0000030c 00000104H .CRT$XIA                DATA
 ...
```

**A list of symbols (functions and data)**

```
  Address         Publics by Value              Rva+Base       Lib:Object

 0000:00000000       ___safe_se_handler_count   00000000     <absolute>
 0000:00000000       ___safe_se_handler_table   00000000     <absolute>
 0000:00000000       ___ImageBase               00400000     <linker-defined>
 0001:00000000       __enc$textbss$begin        00401000     <linker-defined>
 0001:00010000       __enc$textbss$end          00411000     <linker-defined>
 0002:000003a0       _wmain                     004113a0 f   console4.obj
 ...
```

You can tell apart the functions from variables by the "CODE" / "DATA" designaiton in the segment list.

Advantage: You will get all symbols, even those in libraries, that were not removed by the Linker.

Disadvanatge: You will get all symbols, even those in libraries, that were not removed by the Linker. I don't know of any tool that does the code/data separation automatically.

Comment: Given that you can find the globals there in the segments table, how can you determine which source files they are coming from? Thanks.

Comment: @NHDaly: there is no explicit information in the map file (could be retrieved from the debug info), but usually the object file is enough, e.g. console4.obj virtually always comes from a console4.cpp.

Comment: thanks, agreed. I was getting this information through dumpbin, but that doesn't work on .obj files. I will try this option instead.
Can you specify /MAP when compiling with the Visual Studio Console Tools rather than the application itself? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know the http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer program (product of google)  which can work in Windows and on compiled code. It is dynamic instrumentation program (like valgrind or bit like qemu/virtualbox), which add some checks to memory accesses. It will try to find some threading problems. You can just run your program under control of threadsanitizer. There will be slowdown from dynamic translation and from instrumentation code (up to 20x-50x times slower). But Some problems will be detected automatically.

It also allows you to annotate some custom synchronization functions in source code.

Wiki of program has links to other thread-race detectors: http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/RaceDetectionLinks

Answer (score 2):

[cppclean](https://github.com/myint/cppclean) is a static analysis tool that can help you. From the documentation:

```
cppclean finds global/static data that are potential problems when using threads.
```

A simple example with a static local variable and a global variable follows.

./example.h:

```
void foo();
```

./example.cpp:

```
#include "example.h"

int globalVar = 42;

void foo(){
    static int localStatic = 0;
    localStatic++;
}
```

Open a terminal and run cppclean as follows:

```
$ cppclean --include-path . example.cpp
example.cpp:3: static data 'globalVar'
example.cpp:6: static data 'localStatic'
```

Unfortunately, cppclean has some [parsing issues](https://github.com/myint/cppclean/issues/146) and [bugs](https://github.com/myint/cppclean/issues/140). However, these issues are pretty rare, and affected below a percent of all code I've tested.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) by using its code query language

```
from  f in Fields where f.IsGlobal select f
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `dumpbin` tool will help here. You can run it with `/SYMBOLS` key to display the COFF symbol table and look for External symbols - global variables should be in this list. [DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You all are making this too complicated.

1.
Copy the code of each of your files (one at a time separate from the others) to a string or a wide string or etc. and then parse out everything that is from "{" to "}" uninclusive. Save the result to an exterior file. After the first time, then append to that file.

2.
Even if you have 1,000 lines total of what is left after all that parsing, in that are all of your globals (depending upon how you created the globals). If you created them via a namespace, etc. then go back and parse for that. I doubt that most programmers will have 1,000 globals, but for some applications it might be what they use. If you do not have too many at that point then manually edit that text file of the results.

I have found that maybe 90+ % of the answers on this site are bloated with far too much complexity that just eats up cpu time and memory space. Keep it simple.

You might find it handy to have a globals.h file which you load early and keep most or all of you globals there. It looks like time to do a lot of clean up.

Comment: Re *"parse out everything that is from "{" to "}" uninclusive"*: The source code might be much more complex than that, especially if macros are involved.